# Android - Edit XML through Java

Tags: android

Is it possible to change XML through Java?
I've got a duration:

```
<translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="10000"/>
```

I need to change the "android:duration="*int*" to a user input.
Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change what's in the xml at runtime. resource files can't be changed once they're compiled. But you can change some properties in Java. Here you would set it on your animation object

If you look at that property in the Docs then it will show you if it has a Java counterpart.

This one looks like it has [setDuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setDuration%28long%29)(long). So it has a function but you will have to convert your `int` to `long`.

Comment: How would you call the XML code in Java? I'm sure it won't just be the name of the file and .setDuration?

Comment: It's <set>, so there's not any possible way? It's a transition, so when the activity is called there's a transition. I guess I'll look up how to create a transition through the Java code instead of XML format, then at least I can change the properties.

Comment: Right, you can't change it. I have just started getting into animation more so I can't tell you much about that...just about Java and how the Android framework operates (what parts I know). I believe you would need an animation object and you set your properties on that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, thanks. It helps a little, I thought you wouldn't be able to. But somewhere I saw a tutorial on how to make an activity transition through Java (which means you can change the properties).

Comment: Right, you can change the animation properties but you can't change what is in the xml file

Comment: But the code/file isn't used at runtime, so I can't change it even once the program has been compiled?

Comment: That sucks. I wish I could just make the transition through Java instead of XML.

Comment: You still can as I said in my answer by creating the `translation` object and using `setDuration(int)` and put the user input inside there